# Как решить проблему с кодом? ВК-API

Tags: vkontakte-api

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.vk.com/method/audio.get?owner_id=171166379&count=81&access_toke…09b13baa888c131fb310a1221cd086b043sa22wqd. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://w-0rld.ru' is therefore not allowed access.
```

- Такая ошибка выходит когда я хочу получить аудиозаписи.
`getJSON('https://api.vk.com/method/audio.get?owner_id='+id+'&count=81&access_token=' + token, function(t) { ... ...`
Как я понял, вк не дает получить список - стоит какой-то запрет. Есть другой способ получить данные?

Comment: когда получали `access_token` вы запрашивали права `scope` на аудио `audio` ? если нет, то надо бы

Answer (score 2):

Надо было добавить аргумент: crossDomain.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.vk.com/method/audio.get?owner_id='+id+'&count='+feo+'&access_token=' + token,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function(data){
    var e = data.response;
    $("#box").html(TPL_find);
    for (var n in e) {
                songs.push(data.response[n].url);
                titles.push(data.response[n].artist + " - " + data.response[n].title);
                $("#box").append('<div class="t" id="t' + n + '" title="' + data.response[n].artist + ' - ' + data.response[n].title + '"><a href="#" onclick="play(' + n + ');return false;">' + data.response[n].artist + ' - ' + data.response[n].title + '</a><a href="' + data.response[n].url + '" target="_blank" style="float:right;">&darr;</a></div>');
    }
    $("#box").append(TPL_end);
    $("#t0").attr("style","display:none;");
    }
});
```